# Crear un instalador para Aplicacion desarrollador en Netbeans para una arquitectura específica: 32 bits o 64 bits

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

estoy desarrollando una aplicación bajo plataforma Netbeans(Netbeans Platform Application), y sé como generar un instalador usando click derecho, packages as > Installers. Pero no logro generar un instalador para 32 bits o para 64 bits. Como puedo hacer eso en Netbeans?

Comment: Java es multiplataforma, no deberías tener detalle con eso. Es mejor que crees un .jar para evitar esos problemas.